# Foreground Service's Notification Only says "xxx is running ... Tap for more information..."

Tags: android

I wanted to implement a foreground service with an ongoing notification. So far I just want some proper title and some text, but even that doesn't work. Android only shows

"AppXXX is running

Tap for more information or stop app"

The code of making the notification is as followed:

```
    Notification notification =
            new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("title")
                    .setTicker("ticker")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

setSmallIcon(...) is required for the notification to show properly. According to the anatomy of an android notification [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications):

> Small icon: This is required and set with setSmallIcon()